# Cucumber + JUnit5: No tests found for given includes

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, junit5, spring-boot-test

I'm using Cucumber and JUnit5 to write tests for my projects. My project uses Spring Framework and Gradle as a build tool and I use IntelliJ Idea as an editor which has Cucumber and Gradle plugins. Here is my Cucumber's runner:

```
package com.mycom.myproject.cucumber;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.*;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.*;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("src/test/resources")
@ConfigurationParameters({
            @ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.mycom.myproject.cucumber.steps"),
            @ConfigurationParameter(key = FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "src/test/resources/cucumber"),
            @ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "html")
})
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

This is my cucumberBootstrap class:

```
package com.mycom.myproject.cucumber;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

import com.mycom.myproject.Application;

import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, args = "spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration,com.arkea.catalyst.kafka.spring.KafkaAutoConfiguration")
@ActiveProfiles({ "IC" })
public class CucumberBootstrap {
}
```

My steps definition class:

```
package com.mycom.myproject.cucumber.steps;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class StepDefinition extends CucumberBootstrap {

    @Quand("I want to calculate my bill")
    public void iWantToCalculateMyBill() {
         // some code
    }

    @Alors("I have this result")
    public void iHaveThisResult() {
         // some assertions
    }
}
```

Here is my gradle.build file:

```
   // Tests dependencies
   testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
   testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
   testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
   testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
   testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.1.2'

   testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:$cucumberVersion"
   testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:$cucumberVersion"
   testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:$cucumberVersion"

   testImplementation "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine"
   testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite:1.9.0'
   implementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.9.0'
}

test {
   useJUnitPlatform()
   systemProperty 'java.util.logging.manager', 'org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager'
   testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
   testLogging.exceptionFormat = 'full'
}
```

My cucumber's version is 7.5.0.
No matter how I change the code, I keep having the "no tests found for given includes" error and I have no idea how to change it.
Do you guys have any clue?

Thanks

Comment: In `@SelectClasspathResource("src/test/resources")` the `src/test/resources` doesn't look like a classpath entry. You also shouldn't use `FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME`. Have a look at the https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/ for a minimal working example.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. If it's not "src/test/resources", then what should it be? Can you give me the documentation?

Comment: I believe most java courses should have covered what the classpath is. But either way, did you go through the tutorial?

Comment: Well, I see configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output as classpath but the tutorial didn't mention junit5

Comment: I found this example helpful: https://github.com/cronn/cucumber-junit5-example

Comment: Ah sorry. Looks like the tutorial needs to be updated. The maven archetype uses JUnit 5 and converting that to a Gradle project gets you a working project. But that's not actually there.

Answer (score 3):

In your runner class you've got two problems.

### Problem 1

```java
@SelectClasspathResource("src/test/resources")
```

This selects a classpath resource. However `src/test/resources` is not a resource on the classpath.

To explain, consider a simple project you may have the following layout:

```
src
├── main
│   └── java
│       └── io
│           └── cucumber
│               └── skeleton
│                   └── Belly.java
└── test
    ├── java
    │   └── io
    │       └── cucumber
    │           └── skeleton
    │               ├── RunCucumberTest.java
    │               └── StepDefinitions.java
    └── resources
        ├── io
        │   └── cucumber
        │       └── skeleton
        │           └── belly.feature
        └── junit-platform.properties
```

Here `src/main/java`, `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources` are different sources. When you build your project these are compiled or copied the `build` folder:

```
build
├── classes
│   └── java
│       ├── main
│       │   └── io
│       │       └── cucumber
│       │           └── skeleton
│       │               └── Belly.class
│       └── test
│           └── io
│               └── cucumber
│                   └── skeleton
│                       ├── RunCucumberTest.class
│                       └── StepDefinitions.class
└── resources
    └── test
        ├── io
        │   └── cucumber
        │       └── skeleton
        │           └── belly.feature
        └── junit-platform.properties
```

Then when running your tests, the class path is composed of your dependencies and the `build/classes/java/{main,test}` and `build/resources/test` classpath roots.

This means that `io/cucumber/{Belly,RunCucumberTest,StepDefinitions}.class` as well as `io/cucumber/skeleton/belly.feature` are all resources on the classpath.

And because `@SelectClasspathResource` selects a class path resource you should use `@SelectClasspathResource("io/cucumber/skeleton/belly.feature")`. If you have multiple features in `@SelectClasspathResource("io/cucumber/skeleton")` will also work.

### Problem 2

```java
@ConfigurationParameter(key = FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME, ..)
```

The `FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME` only exists because Maven and Gradle don't support JUnit5s discovery selectors from the command line. You don't need it in this case.

Comment: Hello, I tried to implement your solution but it still gives me the same error. This time I removed the "key = FEATURE...." and change the classpath to "com/mycom/myproject" which is the classpath that I found inside the build folder

Comment: Then maybe there is something else that doesn't match up. The https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton contains a working example (with a failing test) for Gradle. You can compare against that one. Do make sure to use all the flags from the docs when using gradle  `./gradlew test --rerun-tasks --info` otherwise Gradle won't show you the problem on the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close!
In your `RunCucumberTest` class:

1. Add

```
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
```

2. Remove

```
@ConfigurationParameter(key = FEATURES_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "src/test/resources/cucumber"),
```

And then put your feature files under:

```
src/test/resources/features/
```

By the way, you don't need:

```
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ever since JUnit evolved from version 4 to version 5 there were a lot of very strong and powerful features implemented.

In JUnit 5, the `@RunWith` annotation has been replaced by the more powerful `@ExtendWith` annotation. However, the `@RunWith` annotation can still be used for backward compatibility

Just add the following if one is using Gradle and your error should be fixed:

```
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine")
```

For Maven add:

```
<groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>your_version_here</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
```